# Weird Excel 2010 VBA Window Behaviour

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop, microsoft-excel-2010, vba

If I open Excel and then open the VBA window then close it, every time I RDP to my computer, the VBA window is open again, even if I closed it before disconnecting.

The next time I am sat locally to my computer, it is open also, but if I close it, it remains closed until I RDP etc.

Has anyone seen this behaviour before?

Comment: Open it, or run VBA?

Comment: @Raystafarian I only ever open it to change a function I have written or to write a new one. I have not tried just opening the window and doing nothing but closing it. It doesn't happen unless I first open the VBA window though.

Comment: Is this in every file or just a specific file?

Comment: I have seen this in 2 files now.

Comment: What about files that don't have any VBA? Does it happen with them? Maybe the code is flawed is what I'm getting at.

Comment: as in my code? I can't see why that would open the window when I RDP... :/ It doesn't do it to any file without VBA. Maybe you can create a file and add a line and see if it happens for you. I can repeat your steps to see.

Comment: I wonder if, the VBa is creating a handle to something which even though you shut it which the session is remembering...